# Visual Studio Community does not build my Angular app

Tags: angular, visual-studio, build

I want Visual Studio to produce a build of my default angular project into the dist/ folder so that I can deploy it.

I have created the default Angular app using Visual Studio Community 2022, namely by going to Create New Project, selecting the Standalone Typescript Angular Project and creating this WITHOUT adding the integration for Empty ASP.NET Web API project. I can run the application in Debug mode, by pressing F5, selecting Debug | Start Debugging (or hitting the solid green arrow on the toolbar). So everything is minimal and good to this point.

But now I want to build the application into the dist folder. I have tried Build | Build Solution (F6). I have tried Build | Build AngularProject1 (Shift-F6). Both of these quickly show a status of Build started... and Build succeeded in the bottom left (the status tray). But its clear neither are doing anything.

Does anyone know how to use Visual Studio Community 2022 to actually produce a build into the dist/ folder that can then be deployed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have waited a little longer before posting. I was able to update the `.esproj` file and added ng build to the `<BuildCommand>` text. This is the same as updating the properties page for the project. I had tried updating the properties page previously, but I suppose I didn't save it (??). Anyhow, this worked:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.74-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>npm start</StartupCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jasmine</JavaScriptTestFramework>
    <!-- Command to run on project build -->
    <BuildCommand>ng build</BuildCommand>
    <!-- Command to create an optimized build of the project that's ready for publishing -->
    <ProductionBuildCommand>npm run build</ProductionBuildCommand>
    <!-- Folder where production build objects will be placed -->
    <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\AngularProject1</BuildOutputFolder>
    <CleanCommand>npm ci</CleanCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```